# Java - Case Looping

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement

I was experiment with case statements and I have seem to created an infinite-loop somewhere. I'm not sure why this has occurred. My code loops once and then instead of looping again and asking for another calculated option - it keeps printing out "Unrecognized option..."

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Here's my code.

```
public static void main(String []args) {
    char choice;
    boolean exit = false;
    UserInterface userMain = new UserInterface();

    do {
        choice = userMain.menuUI();

        switch(choice) {
            case 'q':
                exit = true;
                break;
            case 'r':
                Real realResult = realCalculation();
                System.out.println("\nAnswer = " + realResult.toString() + "\n");
                break;
            case 'c':
                Complex complexResult = complexCalculation();
                System.out.println("\nAnswer = " + complexResult.toString() + "\n");   
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("\nUnrecognised option.\n");
                break;
        }
   } while (exit == false);

    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question without seeing the code of `userMain.menuUI()`

Comment: Please post UserInterface code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can only be because `userMain.menuUI();` never returns q or Q

If you want further detail you'll have to provide the code for that.

Comment: Thanks everyone! The problem has now been resolved. The problem was a combination of incorrect values being pushed out which triggered the switch and using the java-dialogue box. It's all sorted now, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the value of `choice` is non of these `case` values (`q, Q, r, R, c, C`) and that is why it's executing the `default` block.

**You said :**

> it keeps printing out "Unrecognized option..."

which is in the `default`, so it is confirm that the value of `choice` is non of the case values.

And as you are not changing the value of `exit` in the default, the loop continues and again comes to the default block and this goes on and on.

Comment: So if the user makes a mistake, instead of being able to try again, the program quits?  That doesn't sound right.

Comment: The intention is to loop again on Unrecognised option, not to exit.

Answer (score 0):

In Switch case if no case statement is matched by default **default** block will be executed.

In your case if the choice is not matched then it will always executes the default case where your not having any condition to break the loop.

If you want the user to give the correct input, Display the meaning full error message or ask him to enter the limited choices